# How much lightning is needed for water spinach and celery?

Tags: hydroponic, spinach

I am a beginner at hydroponics, and want to grow celery and water spinach. However, I do not know what the light requirements (lux) are. Searching online doesn't help at all unfortunately. I have read [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5271/how-much-lighting-do-i-need-for-growing-lettuce-using-indoor-hydroponics?newreg=f05cc7164d5240cda36c2392e2c147be), but this question is asking about different plants.

> Approximately 80-100k will be adequate. Too much more than that (150-200k) and you'll risk having too much which if I recall correctly can cause lettuce to flower (due to the heat concentration). - @Enigma

This answer is for lettuce, but is there such a range for celery and water spinach?

The units can be in [PPFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetically_active_radiation#Units) too.

I have a problem though, I want them to grow in outdoor hydroponics, so the weather is constantly changing, so the light range can vary.

Comment: Hmmm, the *lightning-lit* setup would be *exciting* though I can't imagine it would be a practical source of light...